# Is there an SE site where a question about an uncertain passage in a Greek poem would be on-topic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I once translated (and thus had to reconstruct, in part) the complete poems of Sappho. I am now posting those translations to my blog, along with other translations. As I will have to go over the reconstruction part, I might find some old critical questions such as [this one I asked on Quora](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Who-proposed-version-A-of-this-line-of-Sappho%E2%80%99s-Ode-to-Anaktoria-see-screenshot-in-details-where-why-and-how-supported-is-this-idea), and I was wondering if there was an appropriate place to discuss such issues on SE. Since the language Sappho used is Greek, I figured Greek Language would be the best fit, except it's still in commitment (35%) at the time of writing the question. So I was wondering: is there another appropriate site to use in the meantime (i.e. while Greek Language finishes commitment and enters Private Beta)?

Comment: The only real candidate is [Linguistics.se], but they don't usually  do language-specific stuff. The only other candidate is [languagelearning.se], but that's about acquiring a new lang, not advanced translations. There's a really really outside chance [Latin.se]'d take it, being "people who care about the languages of classical antiquity", and they're still in that "sure, why not?" phase of small, friendly sites. But you'd have to ask on their Meta first. In short, regardless of rules and scope, I just don't think the expertise exists on SE (yet).

Comment: You might try [Mythology](http://mythology.stackexchange.com) or [Literature](http://literature.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 9):

Sure. You can ask your question(s) on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/). We have a number of questions about [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), [translation](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), and [Greek literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek-literature), so come on over and give it a try :)

[image]

<sup>([img src](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/399/481))</sup>